# What is ignore_exceptions flag in laravel 8 config/Logging.php under stack channel

Tags: php, laravel-8

While I was trying to check Project/config/Logging.php option, I came across this code:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],
```

`driver` and `channels` options are documented in laravel documentation but I couldnt find any resource for `ignore_exceptions` option. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a way to tell Monolog to ignore child handlers' exceptions, so that application never breaks if log is not writable and the log method fails. Monolog will catch the exception and handle it silently, insuring that app can finish its job, but at the cost that you potentially will loose the information that you wanted to log (depends on your log channels setup).